# Masked Input Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I need to do an implementation in the "Masked Input Plugin" to make it work masks accepting the following values:

```
(99) 9999-9999 or (99) 99999-9999
```

I tried this:

```
$('.tel').mask('(99) 9999? 9-9999');
```

but if I report the value `(99) 9999 9999` as it renders `(99) 99999-999` I do not want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this nice solution

```
$('.tel').focusout(function(){
    var phone, element;
    element = $(this);
    element.unmask();
    phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
    if(phone.length > 10) {
        element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
    } else {
        element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
    }
}).trigger('focusout');
```

Original code found at

http://pedroelsner.com/2012/07/mascara-jquery-para-novo-digito-de-celular-em-sao-paulo/